# HTTP Error 500 / t_variable error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble solving an issue with this bit of PHP. When executed it keeps throwing this error:

**HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.**

However I do not get this error on my test server, I've tried to find the source of the problem for the past few hours and haven't had any luck, I'm pretty new to PHP and all its wonders, so there could be alot of things wrong with it.

If you could help I would appreciate it!

The faulty code is below:

```
<?php
$keygrab = $_GET["key"];
$user_name = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "database";
$server = "localhost";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
if ($db_found) {
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM `invite_keys`";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
if ($keygrab == $db_field['key'] && $db_field['use'] !='2' && $keygrab !='') {
// print registration information
include ('includes/login-key-invite-include.php');

    }else{

echo "The key is invalid!";



    } 

} 

mysql_close($db_handle);

}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}



 ?>
```

Comment: Check your server's error log, or wherever else you might have PHP logging errors at.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the code, and it worked fine.

Check your php config, or try restarting your server.

Comment: Thank you! What should I look for in the php config?

Comment: Solved problem: FTP'd as binary.